# error al ingresar los datos a la base de datos mysql con php desde el script desde un formulario

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hola estoy tratando de ingresar datos a una tabla recibo desde un formulario pero me da error y ya revise varias veces todo, en un momento me llego a tomar los datos pero la comision la dejo en 0 estan esta basada en el calculo de si hay un corredor que se registra debe sacar el calculo de la comision en base a la prima, les dejo el codigo del formulario y del insert ojala puedan ayudarme y gracias. PD el id del corredor lo trae desde otra tabla como se puede ver en el formulario, el id del usuario en blanco o nulo es 17

formulario

### Ingrese los datos del recibo

```
     <br><br><br>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="prima">Prima:</label>
     <input type="decimal" class="form-control"   pattern="[0-9+{3,30}"  id="prima" required="" placeholder="prima"  name="prima" title="ingrese solo numeros">
     </div>
    
     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="pcuota">Primera cuota:</label>
     <input type="decimal" class="form-control" name="pcuota" required="" pattern=[0-9]{9,2}  id="pcuota" title="ingrese solo numeros y para vacio ingrese 0"><br/>
     </div>

     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="scuota">Segunda cuota:</label>
     <input type="decimal" class="form-control" name="scuota" required="" pattern=[0-9]{9,2}  
       id="scuota" title="ingrese solo numeros y para vacio ingrese 0"><br/>
     </div>
     <br><br><br>

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="tcuota">Tercera cuota:</label>
     <input type="decimal" class="form-control" name="tcuota" required="" pattern=[0-9]{9,2} 
      id="tcuota" title="ingrese solo numeros y para vacio ingrese 0"><br/>
     </div>

     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;

     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="ccuota">Cuarta Cuota:</label>
     <input type="decimal" class="form-control" name="ccuota" required="" pattern=[0-9]{9,2} 
      id="ccuota" title="ingrese solo numeros y para vacio ingrese 0"><br/>
     </div>

     <br><br><br>


      <div id="cod_corredor">
      <label for="cod_corredor"> Corredor:    </label><select name="cod_corredor" class="form- 
       control" class="form-group" >
     
      <?php

      
      $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","losandes");

      $consulta="SELECT * FROM corredor";
      $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

      
      ?>

      <?php  foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones):  ?>

        <option value="<?php  $opciones['cod_corredor']?>" ><?php echo $opciones['nombre']?> 
     </option>
        


        <?php endforeach  ?>


      </select>
      </div>




     <br><br><br>
     <div class="form-group" >  
      <label for="formadepago">Forma de Pago:</label>
     <select name="formadepago"  id="formadepago" class="form-control">
     <option value="Contado">Contado</option>
      <option value="fraccionada">Faccionada</option>
      </select>
       </div>

     &nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;

     <div class="form-group">  
      <label for="frecuenciadepago">Frecuencia de Pago:</label>
     <select name="frecuenciadepago"  id="frecuenciadepago" class="form-control">
     <option value="trimestral">Trimestral</option>
      <option value="semestral">Semestral</option>
      <option value="anual">Anual</option>
      </select>
       </div>

     <br><br><br>




Insert
$prima=$_POST["prima"];
 $pcuota=$_POST["pcuota"];
$scuota=$_POST["scuota"];
$tcuota=$_POST["tcuota"];
$ccuota=$_POST["ccuota"];
$opciones=$_POST["cod_corredor"];
$totalpagado=$pcuota+$scuota+$tcuota+$ccuota;
$impuesto=($pcuota+$scuota+$tcuota+$ccuota)*(0.16); 

if($opciones=17) {
$comision=0;
  }else{
$comision=$prima*0.10;
}
$formadepago=$_POST["formadepago"];
$frecuenciadepago=$_POST["frecuenciadepago"];



require ("db.php");

 $conexionn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","losandes");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "fallo al conectar con la BD";

exit();
}


mysqli_select_db ($conexionn,$nombre) or die ("no se encuentra la BD");
mysqli_set_charset ($conexionn,"utf8");

$consultaa="INSERT INTO recibo ( prima, pcuota, scuota, tcuota, ccuota, cod_corredor, 
totalpagado, impuesto, comision, formadepago, frecuenciadepago) 
              VALUES ('$prima','$pcuota','$scuota'
```

,'$tcuota','$ccuota','$opciones','$totalpagado','$impuesto','$comision','$formadepago','$frecuenciadepago')";

```
$resultadoss=mysqli_query($conexionn,$consultaa);



 if($resultadoss==false) {



echo "error en la consulta recibo";





exit();
}else{

echo "registo exitoso recibo";

}

$cultimo_id=$_SESSION["cod_recibo"]=mysqli_insert_id($conexionn);
```

Comment: Tienes el `action` del formulario? Y cómo envías los datos porque no veo un botón `submit` o lo haces con jQuery?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Coloca TEMPORALMENTE estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script PHP y dinos qué ves en pantalla: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: hola @Bicho disculpen que no se como funciona bien el foro aun, bueno el action esta bien no lo puse porque solo puse el codigo para ingresar los datos a la trabla recibo, el action esta al principio de todo el formulario que son como 3 tablas antes pero en esas si ,e ingresa los datos sin problema solo es la parte de comision que siempre sale en 0 a pesar de tomar el valor de la variable $prima

Comment: hola A cedano, coloque el codigo pero solo me muestra el mismo codigo al correrlo como si fuese extraño o no lo acepta el programa